# Does pgAdmin have auto-refresh and auto-reconnect features?

Tags: pgadmin

Knowing that `pgAdmin III` is a client postgresql that connects to a postgresql server, I have two questions:

- Does `pgAdmin III` have auto-refresh of the data that it shows? If so,
  what is the interval of time?
- Suppose `pgADmin III` has lost connection to the server (for example: a
  network problem), does `pgAdmin III` have auto-reconnect? If so, what
  is the interval of time?

Comment: @VaoTsun what do you mean by `AFAIK`? if the answer is no can you please give me a link.

Answer (score 3):

There's a workaround to keep the connection alive via a configuration file from libpq, the underlying PostgreSQL client library.

When you look at the connection configuration in PgAdmin-III, you will see a "service" option. This refers to the connection service file. To use it, create a ~/.pg_service.conf with contents like:

```
[myappname]
user=myusername
keepalives=1
connect_timeout=20
keepalives_idle=10
```

and when connecting from PgAdmin-III enter myherokudb in the service field.

See this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/729034/any-way-to-keep-connection-alive-in-pgadmin-without-setting-it-on-the-server#answer-729261) for more details.